# True or False, $D_5$ is isomorphic to $S_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If it's true write a proof. If it is false, give a counter example.

The dihedral group $D_5$ is isomorphic to the symmetric group $S_5$

My attempt: I know that $D_5$ is a subgroup of $S_5$. $D_5$ has less elements than $S_5$, so they don't have the same order. Two groups that are isomorphic must have the same order so this statement is false.

Comment: Your proof works exactly -- isomorphisms must preserve order.

Comment: Is it exercise n°0 in your homework list, in the spirit of a very progressive warming up before serious questions ?